# get unserialized array without using get_option()

Tags: wpdb, options

I'm working on a WPMU plugin that cycles through tables in each blog on the network. I can't use get_option to pull the settings array out of the `wp_n_options` tables, so I'm trying to do it by querying $wpdb and then using `unserialize()`.

I know the query is successful because I can `print_r` `result`, but it's wrapped in an array, and I can't figure out how to just get the serialized string out of it.

Any pointers?

---EDIT---

What it's actually returning is this:
`stdClass Object ( [option_value] => ~serialized string~ )`

Comment: Have you tried and use [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) together to get this to work?

Comment: Put this as answer so I can mark it. Thanks a bundle. Wasn't familiar with the switch_to_blog function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two inbuilt functions to do this.

1. **[switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)**
2. **[get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)**

You can use both in the following way to make a function out of it which would give you the option. Put the below in the **`functions.php`** file

```
function wpse_get_options( $blog_id = 1 ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    $get_option = get_option( $option ); // Replace $option with the option name
    restore_current_blog(); // Switch back to the original blog

    return $get_option;
}
```

Now you can use the above function to fetch the options by using the function and passing the blog id/ sub site id.

```
$options = wpse_get_options( $blog_id );
// Replace the $blog_id with blog id of your sub sites.
```